# Difference of purpose of build and dist directories when doing a deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, ant, build-process

I am creating an ant script and I am wondering what should be the name of the directory where I package up the whole kaboodle and make it a .war file and put it in the webapps directory.

Should it be dist or build?

Comment: What about naming it 'war' :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dist.

build is for the .class files only, while dist will include the WEB-INF, META-INF, libraries, etc

Comment: So is build meant to be inside dist since it seems to be meant to contain a subset of the files?

Comment: not generally.  build is usually put into a JAR and that JAR is put somewhere in the WEB-INF or the package structure is copied into WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 3):

Build and dist both contain files created by the build process. But dist contains the ones that you actually want to keep at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Build directory is where files are compiled to. Dist directory is used for the distribution files (a place of the resulting package of the application).

In your case it is obviously dist directory.

Answer (score 1):

- Build will have all individual .jar, .war resource files and ejb .ear
- Dist will have distribution files like ear file with all jars and wars inside it.